# HttpClient Posting to api, getting System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am successfully calling a service using the VS RestClient addin (changes made to protect secrets)

```
POST https://zzz-apis-xyz.com/abc/abc-data/v1/abcbusinessdata HTTP/1.1
X-Special-Client-Id: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
X-Special-Client-Secret: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
accept: application/json 
clientID: cccccc 
content-type: application/json 
abcDistributedKey: ---guid--- 
systemName: chicken

{
    "business": "Hilton",
    "address": "7930 Jones Branch Drive",
    "city": "McLean",
    "state": "VA",
    "postalCode": "22102"
}
```

I am trying to use the following code to post this to the api using the following C#

```
var request = new ApiRequest {
  business = "Hilton Hotels",
    address = "7930 Jones Branch Drive",
    city = "McLean",
    state = "VA",
    postalCode = "22102",
};

var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage {
  Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://zzz-apis-xyz.com/abc/abc-data/v1/abcbusinessdata"),
    Headers = {
      {
        "X-Special-Client-Id",
        "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
      },
      {
        "X-Special-Client-Secret",
        "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
      },
      {
        "clientID",
        "cccccc"
      },
      {
        "abcDistributedKey",
        Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
      },
      {
        "systemName",
        "GLASS"
      },

    },
    Content = new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),

};

using(var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler {
  UseDefaultCredentials = true
})) {
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://zzz-apis-xyz.com/");

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

  try {
    var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    var stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  } catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
  }
}
}
```

This code worked on two days ago but today fails with the error (another dev is also experiencing this) (NOTE: vscode and this C# code are both running on the same machine):

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
> the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
> was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. --->
> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party
> has closed the transport stream.
> at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
> ar)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at
> ThirdPartyData.WebApi.Tests.ServiceTest.d__1.MoveNext()
> in
> ccccccccccccccc :line
> 128
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action
> action)
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
> the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
> was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. --->
> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party
> has closed the transport stream.    at
> System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
> System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)    ---
> End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult, TransportContext& context)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
> ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Comment: This might be a TLS issue, check which version of TLS are you using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to enforce the TLS version something like this

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

You could find some more information about SecurityProtocol [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Net_ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol).